# "Add comment" button overlapping with comment box on Elections page

Tags: bug, election

[image]

As the image shows, on the [2018 Moderator Election](https://android.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) page that button is slight overlapping the comment box. I am using an outdated version of Chromium (v62) but comment boxes and that button displays well on Q&As, so I don't think browser is the issue here.

Comment: Afraid there's nothing we and Android.SE can do about. If that's a general design issue (which I'd suspect), this is better placed at the "global meta".